# youtube.liveChatMessages.list API Explorer

Tags: youtube-data-api, google-apis-explorer

I try list messages from LiveChat of YouTube. Request:

`GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/liveChat/messages?liveChatId=Qfad59EnhUA&part=snippet&key={YOUR_API_KEY}`

Response:

```
404 Not Found
```

```html
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "youtube.liveChat",
    "reason": "liveChatNotFound",
    "message": "The live chat that you are trying to retrieve cannot be found. Check the value of the requests <code>liveChatId</code> parameter to ensure that it is correct."
   }
  ],
  "code": 404,
  "message": "The live chat that you are trying to retrieve cannot be found. Check the value of the requests <code>liveChatId</code> parameter to ensure that it is correct."
 }
}
```

Pages https://www.youtube.com/live_chat?is_popout=1&v=Qfad59EnhUA and
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qfad59EnhUA exist.

What's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

i decide this problem. liveChatId can be get from broadcast for python:

```
print '%s' % (broadcast['snippet']['liveChatId'])
```